# Getting landscape AdMob Interstitials while being in portrait orientation

Tags: android, admob, orientation

The game app I'm currently developing manages its orientation with sensors and is always in portrait mode with this line of code inside `onCreate()` method:

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
```

I've implemented `AdMob` Interstitial ads, however they seem to show up always in portrait mode, probably because the *app thinks it is in portrait mode,* since I'm managing screen rotations inside my game code.

Since I use sensors, I know precisely when in which orientation my device really is, is there a way I could request landscape ads from `AdMob`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the app still calls the `viewWillTransition` function it's quite easy.

Just override the function and use the createAndLoadInterstitial from the [Interstitial Ads guideline from Google](https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/interstitial#use_gadinterstitialdelegate_to_reload) as normal.

Everytime the device will be rotated a new interstitial is requested. But it doesn't work when a interstitial is already displayed on screen.

```
override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
        interstitial = createAndLoadInterstitial()
    }

func createAndLoadInterstitial() -> GADInterstitial {
        interstitial = GADInterstitial(adUnitID: GlobalConstants.interstitialAdUnitID)
        interstitial.delegate = self
        interstitial.load(GADRequest())
        return interstitial
    }
```

As a tip on the side. Introduce a class which dynamically switches AdUnitIDs between debug (test ads) and release (production ads):

```
class GlobalConstants {
    static var interstitialAdUnitID: String {
        #if DEBUG
        return "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/4411468910"
        #else
        return "Production-AdUnitID"
        #endif
    }
}
```